# Retrieving which dependency is importing a specific version of another dependency in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

Been playing with SBT around for a while but still can't find a way to retrieve dependencies that are being used in libraries that I'm using in my project.

I ask this as I've been trying already with `dependencyTree` but no luck so far getting what I would like to.

The problem is that some inner dependency in a library is importing a really old version of Guava, and a dependency that I'm trying to include now breaks because of that mismatch across versions.

So my question is, given a version of a library, say `guava:16.0.1`, is there a way to know which version of which library is including it within the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dependencyOverrides](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version)

For example:

`dependencyOverrides += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "16.0.1"`